# How to upload crawling data using beautiful soup, into AZURE BLOB STORAGE in python?

Tags: python, azure, beautifulsoup, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am crawling data from an URL and for crawling using beautiful soup. I want to store that crawled data into an AZURE BLOB STORAGE as a blob. below is my code when am saving data in my local, same thing I want to perform for direct upload into Azure.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen('www.abc.html')) 
outfile = open('C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\filename.txt','w') 
data = soup.encode("ascii","ignore") 
outfile.write(data) 
outfile.close
```

this code successfully saving data of website in my local folder, please help me with saving the data of the same website in azure blob storage directly. I have key and account in AZURE BLOB STORAGE.

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(urlopen('www.abc.html'))
data = soup.encode("ascii","ignore")        

block_blob_service.create_blob_from_text('containername', 'filename.txt', data)
```

I am trying above piece of code but its not working.

Comment: Please edit your question and include more details about what's not working. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @GauravMantri in my blob code the parameter 'data' is not a text type, and the create_blob_from_text() expect text argument. I am not able to find out other approaches. Castig 'data' to text is giving error as it is a str type.

Comment: Can you convert this data to a byte array?

Answer (score 1):

There is not any information that shows what version of `BeautifulSoup` and the method `urlopen` comes from `urllib` or `urllib2` or `urllib3` in Python 2. Just according to your code, and per my experience, I think you were using `BeautifulSoup4` with `urllib2`, and I tried to reproduce your issue about the `data` type is not `str`, but failed becaused of my code below works.

Here is my sample code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import urllib2

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("http://bing.com"))
data = soup.encode("ascii","ignore") 
print type(data) # It's <type 'str'> here

from azure.storage.blob.blockblobservice import BlockBlobService

block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name='<your-account-name>', account_key='<your-account-key>')
block_blob_service.create_container('mycontainer')
block_blob_service.create_blob_from_text('mycontainer1', 'filename.txt', data)
```

Even I replaced `urllib2` with `urllib`, the `data` type is `str`.
So I think you may try to use the `StringIO` & `block_blob_service.create_blob_from_stream` for your code, as below.

```
from StringIO import StringIO
block_blob_service.create_blob_from_stream('mycontainer', 'filename2.txt', StringIO(data))
```

It also works for me.

Hope it helps.